# pixels matrix to image convertor MATLAB implementation

Tags: image, matlab, pixel

I need to implement the function in Matlab without using iradon() .
is there a way to see how iradon is implemented ? or what functions can I use instead ?!
thanks

Comment: To see how `iradon` is implemented: `edit iradon`

Comment: iradon does not perform "pixels matrix to image conversion". Can you elaborate in what you are trying to do?